# Replacement for SqlConnection and SqlCommand

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, ado.net

I have been writing a lot of `open` and `close` connection to a Microsoft SQL Server database. I'm not sure whether it is the latest technique available for .NET. Is there any latest .NET function that I'm missing?

Example code:

```
protected string InjectUpdateToProductDBString(string Command, TextBox Data, string TBColumn)
{
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuthenticationDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + TBColumn, Data.Text.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        return "Data successfully updated";
    }
```

Is there any replacement for this fussy code technique? Just a discussion to improve my code technique.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for , in place of open and close methods, in any case "using" statement is a good practice and you don't have to call close

Comment: Calling `con.Dispose()` is better because it both closes and disposes the object.

Comment: One replacement that can save you **a lot** of boring, messy boilerplate code is Entity Framework. It gives you a nice, object-based view of your data, and handles a lot of the nitty-gritty details of mapping to and from relational tables, and generates a lot of the SQL statements needed.

Comment: Hi All .. tq soo much for the idea response ...

Comment: @apomene now i know why they use using . it closes the connection once transaction is done . tq

Comment: @Calvin Smith .. Doesnt the con object is disposed once the function call finished perform its algorithm ? or do i missing something ? ... but its a good thing to differentiate it ... care to share ? and thanks .

Comment: @marc_s Entity Framwork .. will look for this .. WCF syllabus i think right ?

Comment: @WanMohdAdzha: I have no idea what you mean by your reference to WCF. WCF is about **services** - `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection` and Entity Framework are about **data access** - two **totally separate**, distinct fields .... WCF has **nothing** to do with data access ....

Comment: @marc_s Sorry my bad ... mistaken exam 516 with 513 ... due to the new exam 487 ... which is a lil bit of both ... Entity Framework is one of the syllabus in 516 - Data Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you enclose your `SqlConnection` in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement. It will ensure the connection is closed even if there is an exception. Also, enclose your `SqlCommand` object in `using` statement, that will ensure disposal of unmanaged resources.

In your current code snippet if there is an exception at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` then your line `con.Close` would not execute, leaving the connection open.

So your method could be like:

```
protected string InjectUpdateToProductDBString(string Command, TextBox Data, string TBColumn)
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuthenticationDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + TBColumn, Data.Text.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    return "Data successfully updated";
}
```

Later you can return a `DataTable` or `List<T>` for your returned rows from the query.

If you want to move away from ADO.Net, then you can look into [Object-Relation Mapping (ORM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which would provide you objects based on your database and easier way to manage your code base. [Entity framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/ef.aspx) is one of them. You may see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend

Comment: using 'using' .. i never know it would close once its done its work . very nice answer . Tq Soo much . Entity Framework will look for it . its the LinQ to SQL right ? .. will try to migrate from old fashioned technique to new one .

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to write it and other tools you could use (like Entity Framework).

However, I recommend that you create a static function (or several) for your data access calls.

```
  protected DataTable ExecuteSqlDataReader(string connection, string sqlQuery, SqlParameter[] cmdParams)
  {

     MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
     cmd.Parameters = cmdParams;
     MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
     sda.Command.Close();
     return dt;

  }
```

Create methods for Getting a dataTable, One value, ExecuteNonQuery, and even break it further down by abstracting out the SqlCommand creation to it's own method.

In any project, this code should be written only a few times.

Comment: `params` is a keyword.

Comment: @Calvin Smith I would say an absolute necessity for maintainable code

Comment: @ChuckBuford lol, I would say one of the ways to have a slight chance to even try to have maintainable code.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Absolutely

Comment: Thanks @Chuck Buford . this is beautifully done . passing an array of parameters and returning value in a Datatable . nice and simple . Thanks again for the idea input .

Answer (score 0):

```
private SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    var con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AuthenticationDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    return con;
}

protected string InjectUpdateToProductDBString(string Command, TextBox Data, string TBColumn)
{
    using (var con = GetConnection())
    {
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + TBColumn, Data.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "Data Succesfully Updated";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yup .. this one is nice . no need to open write the long connection string . just call GetConnection() ... Tq soo much Zer0 for the idea .